# Perform cyclic checks while app is in foreground

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

My app opens a WebSocket connection while it is in the foreground. To do so, I establish the connection in `onResume` and close it in `onPause`.

Now I would like to be able to detect a connection loss to the server, and automatically try to reconnect, while the app is in the foreground.

So the logic would be like this:

- in `onResume` a thread is started
- the thread checks e.g. every 5s if the connection is still open
- if the connection is closed, it tries to reconnect to the server
- in `onPause` the thread is stopped

What would be the best way to implement this with Android/Kotlin? Should I use Threads, Coroutines or something else? What would a simple example look like?

Comment: Why not just build auto-reconnect logic into your web socket code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use kotlin co-routines, here is the code...

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeat(Int.MAX_VALUE) {
        Log.d("Checking for connection")
        delay(5_000)
        isConnectionStillAlive()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way would be like this.

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) // For custom control

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        checkConnectivityEvery5Seconds()
    }

    private fun checkConnectivityEvery5Seconds() {
        scope.launch {
            while (true) {
                // Perform your task here also Wrap your task in a try-catch block
                // to handle exceptions gracefully and prevent them from crashing the coroutine.
                delay(5000) // 5 seconds
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        scope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    }
```

Note: this coroutine will be running off the UI thread. So, if you are updating any views to show that connectivity status then you need to do like this.

```
private fun checkConnectivityEvery5Seconds() {
        scope.launch {
            while (true) {
                // Perform your task here also Wrap your task in a try-catch block
                // to handle exceptions gracefully and prevent them from crashing the coroutine.
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    //update your ui
                }
                delay(5000) // 5 seconds
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After pausing and then resuming the app, the coroutine seems not to be started again.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention. a coroutine cannot run on the same scope after cancellation. Edited the answer with solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a coroutine. To get a `CoroutineScope` to launch that coroutine use `lifecycleScope` extension property. This scope will get destroyed and cancel all its coroutines when `LifecycleOwner` is destroyed. To attach the coroutine to a certain lifecycle state you could use `repeatOnLifecycle` extension function. The following coroutine will be started when lifecycle is in resumed state and canceled when it's paused.

To launch the coroutine in a specific thread pool designed for blocking IO operations you probably (depends on your check/reconnect implementation) should specify `Dispatchers.IO` as `context` argument to `launch`. But it would be better if your check/reconnect functions are [main-safe](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#main-safe) and that is not necessary.

In `onCreate`:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
        while (isActive) {
            delay(5000L)
            // Connection check
        }
    }
}
```